# Save output of previous command to a text file

Tags: command-line

Suppose I ran some command, and now want to save the output of that previous command to a text file (without re-running the command, of course, there's no reason to assume it's idempotent).

Is there some simple way to get that output of the previous command?

```
echo <magic_for_last_output> >file.txt
```

Comment: Just found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283097/reusing-output-from-last-command-in-bash,  it looks like hacking bash would be the necessary route to accomplishing this...

Comment: You could use [`script`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/script.1.html) to log your bash session.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a way to save the last command's output to a file, as far as I know. The shell doesn't store that information.

However, you can hit the up arrow <kbd>↑</kbd> and add the redirection to the end of the last command, so you don't have to type anything new.